# What triggers the "continue in chat" prompt?

Tags: support, chat

I noticed on a recent question of mine that after I and another user discussed something in the comments a prompt (below the comments) came up saying something like "Please keep comments to a minimum, if you'd like to make a chat room, and continue click here". That isn't verbatim what I got, but it was something like it.

How does the system detect this? Is it looking for keywords or is there a comment count that triggers it? I ask, because I want to know, and to learn when or when not to continue commenting.

Comment: Pretty sure it just counts the number of unbroken messages between two users.  If someone else interjects, the message disappears, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prompt is given when two users engage in comments, with no one besides the two, for at least 6 messages between the two of them. Well, specifically, it's 3 per person, but in general that means 6 messages lest someone is putting a ton before response. There's also a time limit requirement - if there's a big span of time (currently 4 hours) between the comments (not just two adjacent, but the entire conversation from start to finish), then it won't prompt.

Note that on Meta sites, the amount per person increases to 4. Just to be that much more complex.

Comment: I don't get the option on [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129987/42984) which has 7 comments between me and 1 other user.

Comment: @Batophobia My understanding is that the message goes away after several days but I'm still getting confirmation on that.

Answer (score -5):

As the help text in the Add Comment box states:

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.  Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

So as long as the comments are improving the post, they should be fine.  If you are having a discussion about it, it belongs in chat/meta.

In the end, comments can be deleted later, so no big issues with having too many (so long as the post is improved and the comments are then cleaned up).

As far as how the system determines when it pops up, it is not strictly the number or comments.  [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35286/42984) has 14 comments but I am not given the option to "Continue in chat".  It also does not appear to be 2 users commenting back and forth.  [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/129987/42984) has 7 comments between me and the OP but I still do not have this "Move to chat" option.

So to get the "move to chat" it must either require more then 7 comments between users, more then 14 total comments, or pick up on certain keywords.